# Word crashing with formulas

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Here is a video of what is happening: https://streamable.com/nrsc5

In this case it's just an example, but as I am writing a paper, this causes just too many crashe. I have already tried reinstalling office, no luck.

Comment: Have you tried editing in a Word-compatible browser such as free LibreOffice Writer? It might be more stable than the particular version of Word on your PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deselect the check boxes inside "**proofing options**", this will cause less crushes in word either you are writing formula or typing in some other languages. Go to Word **File > Options > Proofing options**.
[Deselecting Word proofing options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNbgC.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the default printer that Windows is using:

Go to **Settings** -> **Devices** -> **Printers & scanners** and select **Microsoft Print to PDF** -> **Manage** then click **Set as default**.

It's ridiculous, and very Microsoft, that this works...

Comment: what a life saver! this solves the problem where word crashes on selecting formula structures. BTW, if there's not a "set as default" option, you need to turn off "Let Windows manage my default printer".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but Word, PowerPoint and Exel would crash after I inserted the equation's script. I solved this by fixing Microsoft Office. By going to **Settings -> Apps -> Apps & Features**, I have done and select **Microsoft Office** and select button **Modify**, then the verification window pops up, press yes. There are 2 selections: Repair Offline/ Repair Online, my problem was solved by selecting an online repair. After installation, everything was fixed.